# Unable to increase width hth of react card element

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to increase width of card element because the text is flowing out of the card element. Here is my code

```
<div style={{ width: '1200rm' }}>
      <Card
        style={{ width: '100%' }}
        className="responsive"
        showAccentBar={false}
        draggable={false}
      >
   ............
 </Card>
 </div>
```

What am I missing here.

Comment: Did you mean to write `rem` instead of `rm`? You can always inspect the element in the browser to see any warnings in your styles

Comment: Agree with @mousetail, possible problem in RM instead rEm

Answer (score 0):

The `rm` at first line is not a available CSS unit, please try `1200px` or `1200em`.

Comment: If I increase the width inside <Card
        style={{ width: '100%' }}, it increases the width of padding behind the card, but it does not increase the card width, characters still flow out of card, only padding behind card is increasing .